# Looking to apply a functioning KB, MB,GB script to specific column in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I am complete noob to scripts, java and all things code but i need to get a script working on a google spreadsheet of mine.

Its a file inventory and I need to convert raw bytes to KB, MB,GB.

I tried a formatting ajustment on the cells themselves but that gave me incorrect calculations something to do with 1000 vs 1024 values

I have a script that works im just not sure how to get it into my spreadsheet.

(Spare me corretions on my improper use of coding grammar, I am not trying to become a better coder I just want to get this thing working...)

Here's what I want to implement to my google sheet

```
function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';

    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';

    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}

Comment: Java is to Javascript like ham is to hamster or car to carpet. They just share a common prefix.

Answer (score 12):

Some googling lead me to: https://gist.github.com/loganvolkers/933af8513ed8c2268f59c85a31761a43

Select your cells, go to `Format` menu, then `Number`, then `Custom Number format` and paste the following:

```
[<1000000]0.00," KB";[<1000000000]0.00,," MB";0.00,,," GB"
```

Credits to @loganvolkers.

This is how it looks like (applied to the 2nd column)

[image: Byte format]

Answer (score 0):

### You can insert KB, MB,GB as a cell format and using sheet functions

By clicking a column and then click on **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format** and fill it with **0.00 KB**, **0.00 \MB**, **0.00GB** (note that character M is special here) adding as many decimals as needed.

[image: Format]

Once you've done that go to the KB column and use the following sheet function `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A2:A/1024))` keep in mind this is just an example and you should change the range. The same goes to MB and GB `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(B2:B/1024))` or `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A2:A/(1024*1024)))`-

### As a different approach you can bind your Google Apps Script to your Spreadsheet

You can find how to correctly use Google Apps Script and Sheets [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) or you can add the [Advance Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) which allows you to interact with the API itself.

Bear in mind:

- The script should be [bound to your Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). Otherwise you've got to open it by using ID like  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");`
- The following functions are useful in your specific case [getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet), [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation), [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Hi Jose thanks for jumping on this.

Any chance you could break this down further as theres some intial steps I think I'm missing, also I actually only need one column to read in GB eg I need to get 6049805980 to be 5.63 GB. 

I have several clips names in one column and thier file size in the next. but this it in bytes and i need a formula to accurately convert that to GB

Comment: After playing with ti for abit longer I've got it to work! Thank you so much